# update MySQL поверх старого значения

Tags: mysql, update

- Есть `TableA` с колонкой `ColA`, значение которой получается по `ID=2`.
- Есть ETL задача, которая выгружает XML файл в формат `- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
  Получается у меня множество строк:

> `- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
> ...

В этом случае всё в порядке.
**Вопрос:** Как можно обновить значение колонки, чтобы каждая последующая строка из XML вводилась в новую строку.

**Что есть сейчас:**
В значение колонки попадает только последнее значение `- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"` XML файла. Это логично, раз `UPDATE` и каждый раз только 1 значение попадает (по одной строке перебирается).

**Ожидаемый результат `ColA`:**
`- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
`- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
`- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
`- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"`
`...`

**Важно**
Каждый `- "text1"_"text2"_"text3"_"text4"` с новой строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET column = CONCAT_WS('\n', column, @line_to_add) 
WHERE id = @id
```

Возможно, разделитель `'\r\n'` - зависит от ОС (точнее, от text style - `\n` для *nix и `\r\n` для Windows).

Ну или можно так: `CONCAT(column, '\n', @line_to_add)`. Без разницы.